# Fatal error: Call to a member function escape() on a non-object in .....on line 10

Tags: wordpress

i am making a simple javascript login form for wordpress. i have the form submitting to the following bit of php to handle the login:

```
<?php
get_header(); 
global $user_ID;


if (!$user_ID) {

    if($_POST){
        //We shall SQL escape all inputs
        $username = $wpdb->escape($_REQUEST['username']);
        $password = $wpdb->escape($_REQUEST['password']);
        $remember = $wpdb->escape($_REQUEST['rememberme']);

        if($remember) $remember = "true";
        else $remember = "false";
        $login_data = array();
        $login_data['user_login'] = $username;
        $login_data['user_password'] = $password;
        $login_data['remember'] = $remember;
        $user_verify = wp_signon( $login_data, false ); 
        //wp_signon is a wordpress function which authenticates a user. It accepts user info parameters as an array.

        if ( is_wp_error($user_verify) ) 
        {
           echo "<span class='error'>Invalid username or password. Please try again!</span>";
           exit();
         } else 
         {  
            echo "<script type='text/javascript'>window.location='". get_bloginfo('url') ."'</script>";
            exit();
          }
    } else { 

//get_header();

?>
```

any ideas on why i am getting the error? 
Cheers, Dan

Answer (score 0):

You are using `$wpdb` object and calling the script by `ajax` that is probably not available (the error message says that) in your script, to use `$wpdb` in your script use the following line first to connect your script to Wordpress

```
include "/path-to-wordpress/wp-blog-header.php";
```

In order to access `$wpdb` from inside a function, you have to define it in the global scope as follows

```
function my_function() {
    global $wpdb;
    $wpdb->query('...');
}
```

This file is located in the root directory of your WordPress installation.

Comment: but isn't wp-blog-header.php already getting called if i am calling get_header?

Comment: Is that working, your `get_header()` function, can you post the js code, how you are calling that script ?

Comment: get_header is in the code above. i have created a function and put global $wpdb; in the function. the error has gone, but its still not working correctly